# Present a popover in UITableViewCell with UIButton Action

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a custom UITableViewCell which contains a UIButton. when I press the button I want to display a popover with some text. The text will vary depending on the indexPath pressed.

below is my code so far.

```
class CellButton: UIButton {
 weak var myTable: UITableView?
 weak var myCell:  UITableViewCell?
 }
```

This is my custom UITableViewCell. I have a button action that prints a line, I want to instead display this as a popover.

```
class CourseworkTableViewCell: UITableViewCell,  UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var courseworkName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var courseworkMark: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var courseworkValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var courseworkReminder: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var courseworkDueDate: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var viewNote: CellButton!

@IBOutlet weak var courseworkProgressBar: ProgressBar!
@IBAction func viewNotePressed(button: CellButton){

if let myCell = button.myCell, indexPath = button.myTable?.indexPathForCell(myCell) {

    let entry = courseworks[indexPath.row]
    print(entry.valueForKey("courseworkNotes") as! String)




}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**ViewController.swift**

1.In cellForRowAtIndexPath assign tag for button

```
  cell.myButton.tag=indexPath.row
```

2.In IBAction for button,you can access that tag..

```
  @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

     let entry = courseworks[sender.tag]
     //here you can implement a alertView to show popover 
            //according to your requirement
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a gesture recognizer in your table, an detect if a cell was pressed, and which was.

Declare a property like this:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer * lpgr
```

Then:

```
func setUpLongPressGesture() {
    self.lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleLongPressGestures:")
    self.lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
    self.lpgr.allowableMovement = 100.0
    self.myTable.addGestureRecognizer(self.lpgr)
}

func handleLongPressGestures(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.isEqual(self.lpgr) {
        if sender.state == .Began {
                //Get the table indexPath
            var p: CGPoint = sender.locationInView(self.myTable)
            var indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.myTable(forRowAtPoint: p)
            //if indexPath==nil means long press on table view but not on a row
            if indexPath != nil {
                var cell: UITableViewCell = self.myTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
                if cell.isHighlighted {
                    NSLog("long press on table view at section %ld row %ld", Int(indexPath.section), Int(indexPath.row))
                    self.currentIndexPath = indexPath
                    //Do your stuff
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // End sender isEqual longPress
}
```